# Does dataform support CTE's or Subqueries?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataform

I am quite new at Dataform, so I have the question if sqlx files allow using common table expressions (CTE's) or subqueries

Thanks

I couldn't try anything yet cause Dataform is not enabled yet in my company but I am translating some of the SQL files to sqlx.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, Dataform will handle your SQL the same as BigQuery. The only additional work will be adding config data at the top of the file and moving all your table/function references to Dataform.